# How to hide body field in a view only on certain content types

Tags: 7, views, hooks

I have a search result view of different content types, and i want to show the body field (trimmed) on some content types, but show no body on other content types. Since they all share the same body field, I would need to exclude the body field from displaying on the content types that I don't want to see them on.

Right now I am doing this with Views rewrite results and CSS. I add the content type field and exclude, then add the body field. Under rewrite results I rewrite the output of the body field with this:

`<span class="search-body-[type]">[body]</span>`

I then hide the content type bodies that I don't want to see with CSS:

```
span.search-body-MY-TYPE1,
span.search-body-MY-TYPE2 {
  display: none;
}
```

This works "visually", but the class and the trimmed body are still rendered in the HTML. Is there a better way to do this perhaps with a `views_pre_render` hook?

(I am completely inexperienced with PHP.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done really easily with [views_conditional module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional). Once you enable the module, having the content type and body fields already added and excluded from display, do the following steps:

1. add a views conditional field
2. set the `if` condition to the [type] == Indexed Content: Content Type
3. set `is` condition to `contains`
4. Set the `value` to the content type name for the body that you want to display
5. Then in `Then output this...` Use the [body] replacement pattern

Works like a charm!